# opacity transition not working

Tags: html, css

I am new to css and html and have a very small question. I am trying to add a opacity transition to description of an image when mouse hovers over. But it's currently not working and I am not sure why.

code:http://jsfiddle.net/3VHvM/

my html code:

```
<div class="bucket">
<img src="http://0.tqn.com/d/webdesign/1/0/C/m/1/puppy-in-shade.jpg" alt=""/> 
<div class = "img-overlay">
    <h3>Typography</h3></div>
</div>
```

my css code:

```
.bucket {
width: 31%;
float: left;
position: relative;
margin-top: 1%;
margin-right: 1%;
margin-bottom: 1%;
margin-left: 1%;
text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px;
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,1.00);
overflow: hidden;
    }

.img-overlay {
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,1.00);
bottom: 0px;
color: #FFFFFF;
opacity: 0;
filter: alpha(opacity=0);
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
z-index: 1000;
transition: opacity 0.05s;
-webkit-transition: opacity 0.05s;
-moz-transition: opacity 0.05s;
}

.bucket:hover .img-overlay {
opacity:0.75;
filter: alpha(opacity=75);
}

.bucket img {
width: 100%;
}
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1/20th of a second is too fast to see the effect. Try `2s` instead.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/3VHvM/1/

```
.img-overlay {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,1.00);
    bottom: 0px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    opacity: 0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1000;
    transition: opacity 2s;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 2s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 2s;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

it's working - just too fast for eye to see, you need to decrees the transition speed, try 1s.
this option sets how long will take to the animation to run, 0.05s (s=seconds) it much to fast. 
here:

```
transition: opacity 1s;
-webkit-transition: opacity 1s;
-moz-transition: opacity 1s;
```

Answer (score 0):

your code is correct. Just the time is too less. try 0.5 sec. you will see the output.

Answer (score 0):

The transition may not even be noticeable unless its .5s or slower. Quentin is right .2s is the fastest that it is noticeable if you're looking for it but if you want a viewer to pay attention to it, you should consider going even slower.